# Recursively Parsing JSON Asynchronously

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, asynchronous, recursion

Let's say I have these JSON files:

***company.json***

```
{
  "name" : "Big Corp",
  "employees" : [
    "employees/johnd.json"
  ]
}
```

***employees/johnd.json***

```
{
  "name" : "John Doe",
  "gender" : "male",
  "contact" : "../contacts/johnd.json"
}
```

***contacts/johnd.json***

```
{
  "email" : "jd@example.com",
}
```

They all relate to each other, and each value ending with `.json` is a pointer to another file, relative to the file that it is currently in.

In Node, synchronously connecting these files into a tree is not a hard task, but I'm having some trouble finding a good asynchronous pattern for it. Every time I think I've cracked it in a bug-free and efficient manner, something trips me up again. Perhaps I'm just tired. o_O

I've written a completely synchronous version of what I want, and it works perfectly:

```
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');

function json(jsonPath) {

  var obj = JSON.parse( fs.readFileSync(jsonPath, 'utf8') );

  recurse(obj, jsonPath);

  return obj;

}

function recurse(obj, fromPath) {

  for (var i in obj) {

    if (isJsonPath(obj[i]))
      obj[i] = json( path.join( path.dirname(fromPath), obj[i]) );

    if (obj[i] != null && typeof obj[i] == 'object')
      recurse(obj[i], fromPath)

  }
}

function isJsonPath (str) {

  return typeof str == 'string' && /.json$/.test(str);

}

console.log( json('company.json') );
```

The above code, in combination with the files and structure mentioned previously, returns the correct object:

```
{
  "name":"Big Corp",
  "employees":[
    {
      "name":"John Doe",
      "gender":"male",
      "contact":{
        "email":"jd@example.com"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How would the SO community approach turning this into an asynchronous piece of code? For example, having asynchronous calls to the file system using `readFile` instead of `readFileSync`, such that the following would output the same result:

```
json('company.json', function (err, data) {

  console.log(data);

});
```

Comment: @War10ck _`JSON.parse` doesn't read files as OP wants

Comment: @War10ck note the requiring of files from the file system...

Comment: @hindmost _@nooble_ ah, yes missed that. sorry

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a user of Node, so I'm not familiar with what it can and can't do compared to regular JavaScript, but here's an idea to try.

If a JSON path value is detected, use `Object.defineProperty` to set that key on the object as a getter. This getter will then perform the call to `json` to get that file and replace itself with the file's parsed contents.

This means that the files are only loaded in if they are actually needed, aka "Lazy Loading". In most cases, this should be great even with synchronous file operations.

Your resulting object will look something like this:

```
{
  name: "Big Corp",
  _employees: null,
  get employees() {
    if( this._employees === null) {
      this._employees = json("employees/johnd.json");
    }
    return this._employees;
  }
}
```

This may need some adjustment, particularly because you're defining the array there instead of in a separate "employee list" file, but this should give you a general idea of how to lazy load.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not a huge fan of this idea, not least because I will be returning the resulting data back into the JSON format, so it will loose its functions/methods.

Comment: Ah, yes, in that case you'd need to go ahead with the "lazy loading" of... everything. So it's not lazy any more! This idea is better suited for grabbing bits of data, not necessarily everything.

Answer (score 0):

I would use an async library for a task like this.

For example [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#readme)

The `queue` function looks like it might suit the task, though there are plenty of patterns available. Documentation [here](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#.queue)